# Not working select option dynamic field in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, select

```js
    jQuery(function() {
      var currentCount = 0;
      jQuery('#addMoreEmail').click(function() {
        currentCount = cloning('#MoreEmailDetails', '#MoreEmails', currentCount);
        return false;
      });

      function cloning(from, to, counter) {
        var clone = $(from).clone();
        //console.log(clone);
        counter++;

        // Replace the input attributes:
        clone.find(':input').each(function() {
          var name = jQuery(this).attr('name').replace(0, counter);
          var id = jQuery(this).attr('id').replace(0, counter);
          jQuery(this).attr({
            'name': name,
            'id': id
          }).val();
        });


        // Replace the label for attribute:
        clone.find('label').each(function() {
          var newFor = jQuery(this).attr('for').replace(0, counter);
          jQuery(this).attr('for', newFor);
        });

        // Replace the text between html tags:
        clone = clone.html().replace(1, counter);
        jQuery(to).before(clone);

        return counter;
      }

    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="MoreEmailDetails">
  <div class="form-group users">

    <input type="text" required="required" id="LeadEmailDetail0FirstName" value="" name="data[LeadEmailDetail][0][first_name]">
    <label for="LeadEmailDetail0FirstName">First Name</label>

    <input type="text" id="LeadEmailDetail0LastName" value="" name="data[LeadEmailDetail][0][last_name]">
    <label for="LeadEmailDetail0FirstName">First Name</label>

    <select id="LeadEmailDetail0CountryId" class="select-replace select2-offscreen" name="data[LeadEmailDetail][0][country_id]" tabindex="-1" title="Country">
      <option value="">Choose a country</option>
      <option value="2">SOUTHEASTERN EUROPE</option>
    </select>
    <label for="LeadEmailDetail0CountryId">Country</label>

    <input type="checkbox" id="LeadEmailDetail0PrimaryEmail" value="1" name="data[LeadEmailDetail][0][primary_email]">
    <label for="LeadEmailDetail0PrimaryEmail">Primary Email</label>
  </div ">
     </div">
  <div id="MoreEmails"></div>
  <input type="submit" value="Add More" id="addMoreEmail">
```

In above code input type text and checkbox working fine (adding dynamic fields after click add more) but i m getting below error in case select option

```
TypeError: jQuery(...).attr(...) is undefined
```

Comment: And which line is throwing the error?

Comment: var name = jQuery(this).attr('name').replace(0,counter);
  var id = jQuery(this).attr('id').replace(0,counter);
  jQuery(this).attr({'name': name, 'id': id}).val('1');

Comment: Getting error above code(in last comment)

Comment: And what is that code supposed to do? What is it *not* doing, that it should? What is it doing that it should not?

Comment: The code in your comment is shown as multiple lines in your question. Are all 3 lines throwing that error (3 errors per execution)? Only one? If only one, _which one_? And how do you know that is is the `select` elements that are causing the error?

Comment: if add i select option in code then code not , not creating select option dynamic fields and code work for input type text and radio type(without include select option) and but i need select option also.

Comment: if i hide first line(var name = jQuery(this).attr('name').replace(0,counter); ) then error come second line.

Comment: What if you use `.prop` instead of `.attr`?

Comment: @PatrickQ wow it worked , please answer with explanation how it worked after then i can up vote your answer thanks

Comment: To be completely honest, as far as I know, `.attr` _should_ work. I think your problem might actually be your button.  That's an input element, and therefore is being included in your `clone.find(':input').each(function() {`.  It doesn't have a name attribute though, which could be why the error is being thrown.

Comment: The reason that `.prop()` didn't throw an error is because when it doesn't find a match, it returns an empty string, whereas `.attr()` will return `undefined`. So while it appears to "work", it's not really a great solution. @ariandamnayak's answer below is probably better.

Comment: @PatrickQ , i have checked, we get `checkbox` as input too!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a null check for `jQuery(this).attr('name'))` . [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Arindamnayak/utz8uvzg/)

Following is the modified JS code block.

```
clone.find(':input').each(function() {
    if(jQuery(this).attr('name')) {
  var name = jQuery(this).attr('name').replace(0, counter);
  var id = jQuery(this).attr('id').replace(0, counter);
  jQuery(this).attr({
    'name': name,
    'id': id
  }).val(); }
});
```